# How to continue further development from old changeset in Git?

Tags: git, heroku

The scenarios is as follow:

```
1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 5
```

The head is currently at 5, master branch.
Later we found that changeset 3 to 5 contains unneeded features (but  we don't want to delete those changesets), and we want to continue further development from changeset 2. In future, the changesets rooted from 2 will be the main branch:

```
1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 5

     ^--- 6 <- 7 <- 8 <- 9 <- 10 <- 11 <- ..
```

What is the best way to do it in Git?
We use Heroku and have already pushed changeset 1-5 to Heroku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are in the master branch with a few commits you’d like to rewind but keep the code that you have in a new branch.  Steps are as follows

1. Create a new branch for the current code

   ```
   git branch new-branch
   ```
2. Determine how far back you would like to rewind master

   ```
   git log
   ```

When looking at the log, find the last commit you want to keep and make a note of its hash tag. It will be used in the next step.

1. Rewind/move master back to found commit

   ```bash
   git reset --hard ab15cd26 # (assuming ab15cd26 is the hash tag)
   ```
2. Go back to where you were by checking out the newly created branch

   ```
   git checkout new-branch
   ```

If you wish to push your changes to remote repo, you also need to use

```
git push --force remote-repo master
```

Comment: How the diagram would look like?

Isn't it going to be like: 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 5 <- 6 <- 7 <- ... ?